# Web app calling two times the same method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an `ASP.NET(C#)` application.

In my **HomeController**:

```
    public ActionResult Itens()
    {
        // Do anything here, doesn't matter.

        return PartialView("_Itens");
    }
```

In my **PartialView**:

```
    <div class="itensPaginacaoEstilo">
        <div id="loadingPaginacao" class="divLoadingPaginacao" style="display: none">
            <img src="~/Content/Img/loadingAnimado.gif"/>
        </div>
        <div id="paginacaoProdutos" class="pagination a-paginacao-estilo">
            @Html.PagedListPager(produtosPaginados, page => Url.Action("Itens", new { page, perPage = perPage, filtrosColecao = filtrosColecao, filtrosHierarquia = filtrosHierarquia, filtrosLegendaLinha = filtrosLegendaLinha, filtrosFamilia = filtrosFamilia, filtrosMarca = filtrosMarca, filtrosEstoque = filtrosEstoque, filtrosMix = filtrosMix, chamador = chamador }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "retorno", OnBegin = "MostraLoadingPaginacao()", OnComplete = "EscondeLoadingPaginacao(), MandaParaTopo()"}))
        </div>
    </div>
```

What **`@Html.PagedListPager** generates:

The `Url.Action` in my case implicitly brings a code that will generate a pagination, and in every button of the pagination he brigns me the code **below**.

The **code generated**:

```
<li>
    <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="MostraLoadingPaginacao()" data-ajax-complete="EscondeLoadingPaginacao(), MandaParaTopo()" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#retorno" href="/Home/Itens?page=4&amp;perPage=25&amp;filtrosColecao=1%2C&amp;chamador=0">4</a>
</li>
```

The **Problem**:

My method "Itens" that is referenced by this:

```
href="/Home/Itens?page=4&amp;perPage=25&amp;filtrosColecao=1%2C&amp;chamador=0">4</a>
```

...execute the method "Itens" two times.

**--- Why is this happening?**

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. What code is being called twice? What is the result of it being called twice? What is the expected result? What investigation have you done so far?

Comment: This code calls a method called "Item" in my server, but two times.

Comment: You're going to need to share all the relevant code.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want to call it two times.
That code is just a example, any code that call a method in the server by asp.net runs two times...

Comment: You are still going to need to share all the relevant code, including the `PagedListPager` method (and the values of the arguments that you're passing). As it stands, this could be caused by absolutely anything, including browser extensions if you're writing out URLs of controller actions.

Comment: can you tell us where this is in the lifecycle of the page?

Comment: This is a PartialView of my project. I will try edit my question to make it better.

Comment: *I'm calling the controller Itens just one time in the CSHTML* - No, you aren't. You are calling `Url.Action`, which generates a *string URL* of the controller action. It doesn't call it. None of the code you've posted will actually call that controller action. Something else is happening elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Let me edit again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was going wrong in my project. I was using these two `JavaScript` files:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Then I discovered that **each file** was calling the ajax once.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Researching about these two files I found that they are the same. The only thing that changes between them is that one is more compact than another.

So I deleted the `ajax.js` and left only the `ajax.min.js` on my project:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

And now the methods are hitting just one time. It worked perfectly.